# R Arrange rows by a specific value within a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to arrange the rows in my tibble so that values that have 'Gas' in them go to the bottom of the tibble.

Here's my data:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("ZBottom Gas","Almost Bottom Gas","Top","Bottom Gas", "Top"),
  col2 = c(5, 7, 4, 8,6))
```

This is what I would like the data to look like:

```
df1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("Top", "Top", "ZBottom Gas","Almost Bottom Gas","Bottom Gas"),
  col2 = c(4, 6, 5, 7, 8))
```

I know that I could assign a new variable to anything with Gas in the value to '2' and then everything else to '1' and then use arrangelike so:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("ZBottom Gas","Almost Bottom Gas","Top","Bottom Gas", "Top"),
  col2 = c(5, 7, 4, 8,6),
  arrange = c(2,2,1,2,1))

df2 %>% 
  arrange(arrange) -> df3
```

That works fine, but I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_detect` to detect the presence of `"Gas"` and use it in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>% arrange(str_detect(col1, 'Gas'))

#  col1               col2
#  <chr>             <dbl>
#1 Top                   4
#2 Top                   6
#3 ZBottom Gas           5
#4 Almost Bottom Gas     7
#5 Bottom Gas            8
```

In base R, that can be done using `order` and `grepl`.

```
df1[order(grepl('Gas', df1$col1)), ]
```

Comment: That's perfect! Never heard of grepl, it'll come in really useful though

Answer (score 0):

`regexpr()` also eats tibbles.

```
df1[order(regexpr("Gas", df1$col1)), ]
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   col1               col2
#   <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 Top                   4
# 2 Top                   6
# 3 Bottom Gas            8
# 4 ZBottom Gas           5
# 5 Almost Bottom Gas     7
```